# How to set cin to a member function of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, console, codeblocks

I am making a small console game and I have a `player` class with private integers for the stats and a private string for the name. What I want to do is to ask the user for their name, and store that into the private `name` variable in the `player` class. I got an error stating:

```
error: no match for 'operator>>'   
(operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'void')
```

Here is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Player the_player;
    string name;
    cout << "You wake up in a cold sweat. Do you not remember anything \n";
    cout << "Do you remember your name? \n";

    cin >> the_player.setName(name);
    cout << "Your name is: " << the_player.getName() << "?\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Player {
public:
    Player();
    void setName(string SetAlias);
    string getName();

private:
    string name;
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

Player::Player() {

}

void Player::setName(string setAlias) {
    name = setAlias;
}

string Player::getName() {
    return name;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> name; the_player.setName(name);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return type for the `setName` function is `void`, not a `string`. So you have to store first the variable in a `string`, and then pass it to the function.

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  Player the_player;

  cout << "You wake up in a cold sweat. Do you not remember anything \n";
  cout << "Do you remember your name? \n";

  string name;
  cin >> name;

  the_player.setName(name);

  cout << "Your name is: " << the_player.getName() << "?\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to get the value in the `name` variable from the user and then call the `setName` method of the class `Player`:

```
cin>>name;
the_player.setName(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you surely want use function, should return object reference.

```
string& Player::getNamePtr() {
return name;
}

cin >> the_player.getNamePtr();
```